# Validation for Laravel object variable that is empty or does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I am trying to figure out the best or simplest way to handle a Laravel object variable that is empty or does not exist.

For now I have tried to do this; I have come up with 2 solutions but both of them I feel are not the simplest or cleanest way.

First way is in controller after getting Laravel object, I do a foreach loop and in there I do checking if there is empty or not exist variable, if yes then replace it with '-'.

So in my controller it will be:

```
$dataarticle = Article::with('categories')
                ->get();
             $i = 0;   
            foreach($dataarticle as $data){
                $datas[$i] = array(
                    'id' =>  !empty($data->id) ? $data->id : '-',
                    'name' => !empty($data->name) ? $data->name : '-',
                    'category' => !empty($data->categories->name) ? $data->categories->name : '-',
                    'created_at' => !empty($data->created_at) ? $data->created_at : '-',
                );
                $i++;
            }
```

and in my view I just do another foreach loop in my table.... it looks good but it also means I need to do 2 times foreach.

The other approach is do a variable check in view so I just need to do foreach loop once... but it will make my view code to be messy.. like this

```
 @foreach($datas2 as $data)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bg-aqua disabled color-palette"></td>
                            <td hidden>{{ $data->id }}</td>
                            @if(!empty($data->name))
                                @if($data->id > 1)
                                    <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
                                @else
                                    <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
                                @endif
                            @else
                                <td>-</td>
                            @endif

                            @if($data->hasartikel->count() > 0)
                                <td><a class="btn btn-default" disabled>{{ $data->jumlah }}</a></td>
                            @else
                                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" disabled>{{ $data->hasartikel->count() }}</a> </td>
                            @endif
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

so maybe there is a function or method or command to do it in much more simpler way?

It will be very tiring if you have a lot of variables in your table and keep to do pretty much the same thing for each variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add getFieldAttribute in your model for each field, so it can be used anywhere by just one time config

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return !empty($value) ? $value : '-';
    }
}
```

So , in `view` can simply call the variable as below. No need to reformat

```
<td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
```

Check details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: Does the Laravel core handle cases where an attribute does not exist by returning a default value (like `NULL`)?

Comment: so i just put that function into my model and it will automatically validate the value? or do i need to call this function in my view? like $data->getNameAttribute->name;

Comment: @CharlotteDunois sorry not sure about that, but normally laravel will return exact value stored in db

Comment: wow it works!! at first i am not believe it will be just that easy... thank you man you save so many time!!

Comment: @LaurensiusTony updated my answer for that. simple `$data->name`

Answer (score 0):

Make all you need field required!!!!!!!!! ) and be happy